# Blockchain testnet Websocket

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain

Please, how do I subscribe to blockchain testnet web-socket for an address. I seem to find that for livenet, any help?

Comment: It looks like [blockcypher](https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/bitcoin/#using-webhooks) has a webhook system for both the mainnet and testnet. For testnet3: ``wss://socket.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/test3``